# Problem updating a database field from my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have an update method in my users controller that I call from a HTTPService in Flex 4. The update method is as follows:

```
  def updateName
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    @user.name = params[:nameNew]
    render :nothing => true
  end
```

This is console output:

> Processing UsersController#updateName
>   (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-05-24 14:12:49)
>   [POST]
>
> Parameters: {"action"=>"updateName",
>   "nameNew"=>"ben",
>   "controller"=>"users",
>   "email"=>"email@gmail.com"}
>
> User Load (0.6ms)   SELECT * FROM
>   "users" WHERE ("users"."email" =
>   'email@gmail.com') LIMIT 1
>   Completed in 20ms (View: 1, DB: 1) |
>   200 OK
>   [http://localhost/users/updateName]

But when I check my database, the name field is never updated. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only modified user object in memory, i.e. you are not saving the change to database. You want something like:

```
def updateName
  @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  @user.name = params[:nameNew]
  @user.save
  render :nothing => true
end
```

Additionally you might want to put @user.save in an if-condition to check if model was saved correctly.

Comment: you could also use `@user.update_attribute(:name, params[:nameNew])` which updates the attribute and saves the record immediately. Especially useful in a case like this :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to call update method of your model after you update the fields

```
@user.update()
```